# File obtained via WebClient.DownloadFile disappears immediately

Tags: c#, .net

I've encountered a strange problem, I have a simple service that updates a program, it downloads the file fine, Explorer shows it, but just a second or two after it has been downloaded it disappears from Explorer; and the service which just runs the exe after downloading is unable to start it, because it apparently doesn't exist.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Update();           
}

public void Update()
{          
    WebClient WebClient = new WebClient();
    WebClient.DownloadFile("http://xxxxxxx/xx/test.exe", @"C:\test.exe");
    Load(); //Just runs the exe file.            
}
```

I checked my AV, it isn't blocking it, tested the loading code without the downloading portion, worked fine, the problem only occurs when I try to download it.

Comment: I'll check all the logs and make it a trusted file in the morning and see if that corrects it.

Comment: @dtb The AV has nothing besides email spam checks in the logs, and making the service a trusted file didn't affect it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it was a problem with my server, the file name was supposed to be changed, but it wasn't, so when I called WebClient.DownloadFile it couldn't find the file to download, so it had a 0 byte file on the disk before removing it because there was nothing to download.

Answer (score 0):

Your writing file to `C` root is very telling.

Your program probably does not have the right permission to write to `C:` and instead of getting exceptions, File VirtualStore kicks in and `virtualized` your file access.

Try to search for that `test.exe` and you might find it in some obscure location like

```
C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore.
```

Comment: My service is running under the System account, shouldn't that give it sufficient permissions? I'll try downloading it to the appdata folder and see if that works.

Comment: I searched the entire hard drive for it, but nothing came up.